# Detect only regex in R with nothing before or after

Tags: r, regex

I have a data set with many words per line. I need to detect only numbers with '_' on either side (i.e. _One_) but only if it is the only thing in the line. For example, I would expect:

```
# current regex:

nums <- c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten")

numEx <- str_c(nums, collapse = "|")
```

```
# data

text <- c('_One_: The first one', '_One_', '_Content_', '_Two_: The second one', '_Two_')

df <- as.data.frame(text)
```

```
# current code:

df %>%
     mutate(detect = str_detect(text, regex(paste0("^b_", numEx, "$_/b"), ignore_case = TRUE)))

# have also tried just '^' and '$'; and tried '^' and '$/m'
```

```
# expected output:

_One_: The first one      FALSE
_One_                     TRUE
_Content_                 FALSE
_Two_: The second one     FALSE
_Two_                     TRUE
```

```
# actual output:

_One_: The first one      FALSE
_One_                     FALSE
_Content_                 FALSE
_Two_: The second one     TRUE
_Two_                     TRUE
```

So it is not detecting 'One' or number names that are alone on a line. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor adjustments: add parentheses so your `|` is grouped appropriately. Use `$` at the end of the string, nothing after it. We don't really need word boundaries because you're matching the entire string.

```
df %>%
     mutate(detect = str_detect(text, regex(paste0("^_(", numEx, ")_$"), ignore_case = TRUE)))
#                    text detect
# 1  _One_: The first one  FALSE
# 2                 _One_   TRUE
# 3             _Content_  FALSE
# 4 _Two_: The second one  FALSE
# 5                 _Two_   TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `^_(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)_$` works for me with the case insensitive flag (regex101: https://regex101.com/r/pIlXZn/1), and the one|two|etc bit can of course be replaced by your `numEx` variable.

The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, which allows you to use `|` without also adding the `^_` and `_$` bit every time. If you want to capture the number you can always remove the `?:` so you get a normal capturing group.